# When will we exit beta? What should we look like once we've left?

Tags: discussion

We have 9.5 questions a day, and have been around for 4 and a half years.
We should leave beta soon. Also, any ideas for when we do leave? Site logo etc.

Comment: You'll see in some of the other Beta related threads that some of our statistics are not necessarily the best. Our questions per day is pretty seasonal, hard to get 10 a day consistently, among other things. Leaving Beta may not necessarily be as soon as we'd like.